# Dock not restarting after killall Dock

Tags: terminal, dock, mojave, wallpaper

I recently needed to restart my dock in the terminal via `killall Dock` as I have done many times before. However, after doing so, the dock did not restart and my wallpaper is black:

[image]

This is very worrying as, despite multiple restarts and a host of other attempted solutions, I have been unable to resolve the issue. I have also looked in Activity Monitor for the `Dock` process but I have been shown nothing when searching for it:

[image]

This leads me to believe that the process has not restarted. My question is: How can I restart the Dock process to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for any help, this is a very worrying issue for me as it has greatly limited the functionality of my Mac.

Kind regards, Rocco

P.S. this was the first time I tried killing the dock with that command in OSX Mojave which may be the cause of the problem. Maybe it is an issue with Mojave as I have never experienced this with any previous OSs

EDIT:

This was the exact, full command I ran before the problem occurred: `sqlite3 /$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '~/Desktop/wallpaper.png'" && killall Dock`

Comment: What happens if you open System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app? You can navigate there in Finder or run in terminal: "open /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/"

Comment: Also, this behavior is definitely not standard in Mojave.

Comment: run it again `defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock`

Comment: @Wowfunhappy That did nothing at all unfortunately

Comment: @Buscar웃 I just get `No matching processes belonging to you were found`

Comment: Log in as different user and check it there

Comment: @Buscar웃 The issue does not persist with the test user I created, it is a problem just with my main account

Comment: If you run "/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock" in a terminal, do any messages appear?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Yes, I get the following error(s) [here](https://ibb.co/n7JOSq)

Comment: @Rocco Okay, that confirms why it's not relaunching at least—it can't relaunch, it's crashing for some reason.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I see, that's odd. What would you suggest doing next?

Comment: sorry, just saw your edit, so you tried to modify the desktoppicture.db and it all went wrong...

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes, sorry I forgot to add that to the original post

Comment: @Buscar웃 Do you think the solution mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXBeta/comments/8v71hm/bugs_macos_mojave_removing_wallpaper_and_access/) will work? Seems to be the same-ish problem

Comment: @Buscar웃 Fixed the issue now, I simply deleted the ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db file

Comment: That is what I was going to recommend, but had to get something to eat first :) .... The problem was not the Dock, but the corrupted desktoppicture.db as you found out.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Ahaha no worries, thank you for helping anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Run: `killall 'System Preferences' > /dev/null 2>&1 && rm '~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db' && killall Dock`

For anyone who may experience this issue in the future, my issue was with the file located at `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db`.

After doing some googling, I cam across the following two threads, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXBeta/comments/8v71hm/bugs_macos_mojave_removing_wallpaper_and_access/) and [here](https://www.tech-otaku.com/mac/setting-desktop-image-macos-mojave-from-command-line/). Both of which suggest removing the `desktoppicture.db` with `rm '~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db' && killall Dock` which solved the issue for me. You can read in more detail about the issue and proposed solution on the second of the two linked threads above

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on MacOS Monterey (12.6.1).

I clicked on my desktop and pressed `CMD`+`SHIFT`+`G` (the "go to folder" shortcut in Finder). Then everything started working again.

Restarting may have helped, I just didn't try.

Comment: Damn, makes no sense but it actually worked!

Answer (score -5):

you can just restart your mac and then for me google chrome stopped the restart and the dock was reset so just restart cuz for me nothing worked, hand gestures, f keys, even using ctrl and arrows i had to use spotlight search to open stuff so ya j restart youll be fine

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This answer is very difficult to understand and is at risk of being deleted.  Can you please [edit] it to add the proper grammar, punctuation, and formatting so we can better understand your answer?

Comment: Restarting your computer is what overseas Dell telephone support say. It's not a useful answer for StackOverflow.